# How to select anywhere inside something?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say there's a big group of selectors:

```
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
applet,
article,
aside,
audio,
b,
big,
blockquote,
body,
canvas,
caption,
center,
cite,
code,
dd,
del,
details,
dfn,
div,
dl,
dt,
em,
embed,
fieldset,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
form,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
header,
hgroup,
html,
i,
iframe,
img,
ins,
kbd,
label,
legend,
li,
mark,
menu,
nav,
object,
ol,
output,
p,
pre,
q,
ruby,
s,
samp,
section,
small,
span,
strike,
strong,
sub,
summary,
sup,
table,
tbody,
td,
tfoot,
th,
thead,
time,
tr,
tt,
u,
ul,
var,
video{
    font:inherit;
}
```

How can I make them select only pure elements (without classes) inside anywhere of #some_container? I tried doing it like #some_container strong, but it didn't work properly. When doing it without adding anything as listed above, everything works fine, but it selects elements that I don't need to be selected.

```
<div id="some_container" class="test">
     <a href="https://google.com">Applies here</a>
     <div id="another_container">
         <strong>Applies here</strong>
         <strong class="anything">Does not apply here</strong>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
     <strong>Does not apply here</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to write `#some_container strong` (removing the direct child selector, `>`). Despite that, without a CSS preprocessor like LESS/SASS, you will have to amend each selector.

Comment: it's seems the list of everything, so why not `#some_container *`

Comment: It's not actually list of everything. It seems like that, but it's important to have only listed selectors.

Comment: @chazsolo, it still doesn't work properly. Everything is fine if I leave listed selectors without #some_container, but it selects everything. When I add #some_container in front, it behaves strange.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: `#some_container *:not([class])` will select all descendants that do not have the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with:

```css
.test strong:not([class]) {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="some_container" class="test">
     <a href="https://google.com">Applies here</a>
     <div id="another_container">
         <strong>Applies here</strong>
         <strong class="anything">Does not apply here</strong>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
     <strong>Does not apply here</strong>
</div>
```

Also make sure to close `"` in your `href` attribute.

Comment: About href - I've made a mistake.
Thanks for your reply, but I need only listed selectors, not *.

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer. I hope that it helps you.

Comment: @Andrew if you want to exclude an element with a class attribute, you can use `:not([class])`